# VsCode Flutter Dart Syntax colors, cannot change

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

so i'm moving from Android Studio to VsCode (Android studio killing my ram, macbook pro M1 Pro )
but i can't get the syntax to be colored same as Android studio, i've literally tried everything , tried the scope inspector but it just says source.dart .
i've read and tried every single solution here on stack.
so what i want is to get same syntax coloring as android studio , for the widgets and parameters

this is my android studio :
[image]

and this is vs code
[image]

Comment: check Theme , `Color Theme` on vscode

Comment: that's the first thing i tried and did not work

Answer (score 2):

**First**, you need to install the dart extensions :
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/Dart-Code

**Second**, you open your settings.json file with :

1. **MacOS** : <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> **WIN** : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Write : "settings.json" -> Open the "user" one if you run on your user
   profile
3. Add this code at the root level :

```json
    "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "enabled": true,
        "rules": {
            "property": "#E06C75",
            "property.declaration": "#E06C75",
            // Variables
            "typeParameter": "#ffffff",
            "label": "#f9f5f5",
            "struct": "#fefefe",
            "parameter": "#D19A66",
            "string": "#98C379",
            "variable": "#61AFEE",
            "namespace": "#ffffff",
            "macro": "#f9f8f9",
            "keyword": "#C678DD",
            // String interpolation
            "source.interpolation": "#ffffff",
            // Entity, Type
            "type": "#E5C07B",
            "class": "#E5C07B",
            "type.declaration": "#ffffff",
            // Entity initialisation
            "class.constructor": "#85baff",
            "method.constructor": "#ffffff",
            "function": "#10dfff",
            "method": "#f643ff",
            // Annotations
            "class.annotation": "#ffffff",
            "property.annotation": "#ff4848",
            "annotation": "#E5C07B",
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You **select Dart language** in the bottom bar :
[image: Select Language Model]

Have you downloaded **Dart and Flutter extension**?

*Name: Dart

VS Marketplace Link:* 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code

*Name: Flutter

VS Marketplace Link:* 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

You follow this docs :
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/vs-code

**Your problem does not come from VSCODE but from the graphic theme you are using.**
For you i suggest this theme : 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme

Comment: i have all of them already done, the thing is that everything is working perfectly, except the correct syntax theming

Comment: @MahmoudAbdellatief i have update the answer.

Comment: i tried the theme and still have the same issue as shown in the pictures on my question

Comment: you have to look for a suitable theme.
In VS Code I use the "Visual Studio 2019" theme.
This is link : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kast789.vs-2019-theme

Comment: @MahmoudAbdellatief 
Did you ever find a satisfactory solution?
Was 'Material Theme' the best option?

Comment: I gave up and ended up using the dark material theme